# Changing to tty (ctrl-alt-F1) produces black screen (proprietary nvidia driver)

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, tty

Ubuntu 11.10 works really well with my Nvidia GTS 450 except that when I try to change to a tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>) all I get is a black screen. I can get back to Gnome Shell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

I believe I'm using the 280.13 driver.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I would try disabling the proprietary driver first, and see if that works. If it doesn't, then try accessing the terminal from a different session (Ubuntu, Ubuntu 2D, ect). If it works from there, I would try disabling any Gnome Shell extensions you have enabled, or simply reinstalling Gnome Shell.

Comment: The original poster is referring to real local terminals, not emulated Terminals via Gnome Shell, so messing with that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Plymouth (splash), while nice, is known to cause some issues. Sometimes disabling it will bring back the console.

To try it, reboot, and choose recovery console in GRUB. Then, in recovery mode, choose boot normally and see if your `tty` works.